# Не получается получить данные с страницы с помощью requests?

Tags: python, requests, telebot

Я пытаюсь выполнить код (часть кода телеграм бота):

```
url = "https://tonscan.org/address/EQD-k-39wXjeHsldKepINtt6jbrCYcxLrNZ4me6twhk-stO4"
r = requests.get(url)
with open(f'{rk}.html', "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(r.text)
```

И получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/MrSalaM/tonbot.py", line 501, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "/home/MrSalaM/tonbot.py", line 441, in callback_inline
  File "/home/MrSalaM/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 621, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "/home/MrSalaM/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 695, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "/home/MrSalaM/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 651, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/home/MrSalaM/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 147, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "/home/MrSalaM/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 93, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/MrSalaM/tonbot.py", line 441, in callback_inline
    r = requests.get(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 510, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='tonscan.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /address/EQD-k-39wXjeHsldKepINtt6jbrCYcxLrNZ4me6twh
k-stO4 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))
```

То же происходит, если я использую API... Бот хостится на бесплатном тарифе https://www.pythonanywhere.com/ , может в этом дело? Если нет, то как исправить это?

Answer (score 0):

Забыли отступ

```
with open(f'{rk}.html', "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(r.text)
```

В ответе очевидно 'Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden'. Т.е, коннект происходит, но сервер отдает код 403.

Comment: Так, извиняюсь, это я код неправильно скопировал. С отступом все хорошо, да и по traceback видно, что дело не в этом.

Comment: Возможно дело в том, что сервер хостинга расположен в государстве, где этот сайт под запретом. Как это можно обойти?

Comment: proxy, vpn, если не боитесь за данные - tor